# Recursion definition wont work

Tags: functions

When I try use any function for example

```
  f[n_] := n f[n - 1]
```

and then `f[10]`

I am getting error "Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of...." It seems it tries to compile negative values which is weird. How can I fix it?

Comment: Why would it not try negative values? You need to tell it some known value of f.

Comment: give an example

Comment: As @MariusLadegårdMeyer points out, a fundamental rule of recursive algorithms is to have one or more base/terminating cases. As your function is currently defined, it would never stop calling itself if not for the recursion limit. If you want it not to test negative values, then you need to define `f[0]`.

Comment: I though this program reads n as natural, but it seems to see it as integers which is weird (why integers and not for example reals?)

Comment: Your definition is insufficient.  There are an infinite number of functions compatible with your definition.  Set `f[1] = 1` (for example) to get the Fibonacci series.  Other definitions also work, of course.

Comment: as I said, if these numbers were natural it should work. Didnt know these are integers and go below 0

Comment: *Mathematica* assumes nothing about the pattern `n_` other than that it is an expression. The fact that it deals with integers comes only from the fact that you provided an integer argument in `f[10]` and `n-1` is an integer when `n` is an integer. If you provided a rational like in `f[1/2]` it would deal with rationals, `f[1.23]` would deal with floats, and `f[a]` would deal with symbols and integers (`a-1`,`a-2`,etc.). As stated by multiple users now, you need to define a base case or the recursion does not terminate and become evaluable.

Comment: good to know. Thx

Answer (score 5):

In addition to providing a terminating case, You can also use [`RSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolve.html).

```
Clear[f, f1, f2]

f1[n_Integer?Positive] := f1[n] = n*f1[n - 1];
f1[0] = 1;

f2[n_] = f[n] /. RSolve[
    {f[n] == n*f[n - 1], f[0] == 1},
    f[n], n][[1]]

(*  Pochhammer[1, n]  *)
```

`RSolve` gives a result defined on a continuum rather than just for integer values of n.

```
Show[
 Plot[f2[n], {n, -2, 4.2},
  Exclusions -> {-1},
  PlotRange -> {-10, 25}],
 DiscretePlot[f1[n], {n, 0, 4},
  PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

EDIT: Alternatively, from a sequence generated by `f1`, use [`FindSequenceFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSequenceFunction.html)

```
f3[n_] = FindSequenceFunction[f1 /@ Range[10]][n]

(*  n!  *)
```

This is the same function as `f2` and is defined for more than just integers

```
f3[n] == f2[n] // FullSimplify

(*  True  *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
f[n_] := f[n]= n f[n - 1] 
f[1]=1;
```

Then

```
 f[5]
 (* 120 *)
```

To understand how it works, type

```
 ?f
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I though this program reads n as natural, but it seems to see it as integers which is weird (why integers and not for example reals?)